# NSString parsing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I need to parse this string into three different components:

```
Location: 1|#69.83623|#24.432223|#Cupertino, California
```

The value is stored in one NSString. I need it in three different strings. One string for latitude, one for longitude and one for location.

Any idea how I can do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use this method to get an array of different components:

```
NSArray *bits = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString: @"|#"];
```

Each item in the NSArray will be an NSString.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following

```
NSString *location = @"1|#69.83623|#24.432223|#Cupertino, California";
NSArray *components = [location componentsSeparatedByString:@"|#"];

NSLog(@"%@",components);
float latitude = [[components objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
float longitude = [[components objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];
NSString *loc = [components objectAtIndex:3];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSString *t = @"Location: 1|#69.83623|#24.432223|#Cupertino, California";
  NSArray *k = [t componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
  NSLog(@"components %@", k);
```